# What statistical test is appropriate?

Tags: psychology, hypothesis-testing

I'm running a study that is looking at whether exposure to different conditions can change views. Participants are completing a questionnaire on their views (strongly agree, agree etc.) being exposed to one of 4 conditions, then taking this survey again to see which condition was most influential on viewpoints. Each participant will only see one condition and I'm unsure of which statistical test to use to see which condition is the most effective? Please help!

Comment: So each subject takes the same survey twice ? What are the conditions ? You need to provide more context.